# KDE Plasma insists on staying in dark theme with dark letters

Tags: kde, manjaro, theme, plasma, plasma5

My KDE Plasma insists on staying in a dark theme with dark letters. I've tried changing the theme, but it persists like this. I've already tried logging in with Gnome and switching between the light/dark theme and KDE stays like that.

I'm using Manjaro Gnome with KDE Plasma installed.

I have already installed kde-applications and all dependencies. Same thing remains.

[image]

[image]

Comment: What you do or don't do in Gnome won't and can't change anything in a different DE.

Comment: @ChanganAuto Right...
Then, how can I fix my KDE Plasma?

Comment: Also, already tried typing sudo rm ~/.config/plasma-org.kde.plasma.desktop-appletsrc, and nothing happened.

Comment: I reinstalled KDE Plasma, deleted the .config and .cache KDE files, and nothing happened.